# Не работает robots.txt на Django

Tags: python, django, site, robots.txt, pythonanywhere

У меня проблема с robots.txt, на локальном запуске всё нормально открывается, но после деплоя на хостинг /robots.txt перестал работать, а остальные /polls и /admin работают отлично

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://username.pythonanywhere.com/robots.txt/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

polls/
admin/
robots.txt
The current path, robots.txt/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Вот код в urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from robots.views import robots_txt

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("robots.txt", robots_txt),
]
```

И вот ещё robots/views.py:

````
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET
from django.http import HttpResponse



@require_GET
def robots_txt(request):
    lines = [
        "User-Agent: Googlebot",
        "Disallow: /polls/",
    ]
    return HttpResponse("\n".join(lines), content_type="text/plain")```
````

Comment: А откуда взялся слеш в конце запроса?

Comment: А точно, когда я его убирал, браузер автоматически потом снова его добавлял, я скачал другой браузер и через него зашёл всё заработало!